# Is removing scheme from URL good practice?

Tags: https, url-scheme

I've got a site where I recently started using SSL and now in console I'm getting a couple of errors;

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.XXXXX.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I've read that I could specify the stylesheet as: `//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif` and omit the `http://` or `https://` and let the browser determine which scheme/protocol to use, but I'm surprised I've not seen this before and wondering if this is good practice?
For example, in my Wordpress theme development where I am frequently using `wp_enqueue_style` should I now use this format by default, assuming where you're calling from is able to serve both?

I'm considering just redirecting all traffic to the https version of the site, but still interested to know if this URL scheme is good practice or not?

Comment: If you're planning to edit the source anyway, why not simply change it into https and be done with it. Or are you planning  to switch to another protocol in the future?

Comment: You're right, but that doesn't answer the question which is more out of curiosity over something I only discovered yesterday. On older sites with lots of backlinks to http instead of https it would be good to know the best approach. Particularly for plugin development.

Comment: I don't have an answer to the question "if it works so well, why is nobody using it", sorry. Have an upvote.